# Kubuntu 16.04.3: how to stop KDE from opening apps that were opened before I restarted/shutdown my machine?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

as above.

On OSX, there's an option to disable this feature. I've looked at settings and nothing jumps out as possible option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple: System Settings > Startup & Shutdown > Desktop Session and use the settings in the image:

[image: Settings to ensure clean session on restart]